# How do I retrieve data from a database and display it on an HTML page in springboot?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to get the details of an admin in the database using the username of the admin, but I keep getting redirected to the error page.

This is my admin controller:

```
@GetMapping("/admin-portal/{username}")
public String adminPortal(@PathVariable("username") String username, Model model){
    Optional<Admin> admin = Optional.ofNullable(adminservice.getAdminByUsername(username));
    if (admin.isPresent()){
        model.addAttribute("admin", admin.get());
        return "admin/admin-portal";
    }
    return "error";
}
```

This is the admin repository:

```
public interface AdminRepository extends JpaRepository<Admin, Long>{

    Admin findByUsername(String username);

}
```

This is my admin object class:

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "Admin")
@Table
public class Admin {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "admin_sequence",
            sequenceName = "admin_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "admin_sequence"
    )
    private long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String role;

    public Admin() {
    }

    public Admin(long id, String username, String password, String role) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }

//    Constructor without Id
    public Admin(String username, String password, String role) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

Finally my admin service class:

```
public Admin getAdminByUsername(String username){
    return adminRepository.findByUsername(username);
}
```

What I expected to happen was that once the admin username was in the url AND if in the database, it would populate the thymeleaf template.

This is the template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Admin Portal Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <tr>
        <td>Username:</td>
        <td th:text="${admin.username}"></td>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td th:text="${admin.password}"></td>
    </tr>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: share the stack trace from console, what is the error you get

Comment: please check admin.isPresent() value is true  or false , As you said you are getting error page , means you are getting zero record from db